# How does maven look for transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a gradle project `A`, which I want to export as a library, now I used maven publish plugin to generate pom.xml from its `build.gradle`. And successfully uploaded to local artifactory.

Now I am able to import it in another project, but the dependencies are not being considered.

For example: My library `A` has dependencies `B` and `C`. When I use `A` in a project, it doesn't download `B` and `C`.

I am assuming I did something wrong in generating `A`(not proper `pom.xml`/ or any other mistake).

But I want to know, how does Maven, figures transitive dependencies. Like, which files/locations it scans, where it looks for dependencies?

**Code**

Task for generating `pom.xml` in project `A`.

```
task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'com.a.b'
            version '1.0.0'
        }
    }.writeTo("src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/com.a.b/feature-store-lib/pom.xml")
}
```

The location of my pom.xml is in `META-INF/maven/com.a.b/feature-store-lib/`

I am successfully able to upload in artifactory.

I am able to import properly in another gradle project as well, but its transitive dependencies are missing.

Here is the cropped output of `gradle dependencies`

```
|    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.3.1 (*)
|    \--- junit:junit:4.12
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- com.a.b:feature-store-lib:0.4
+--- io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.22
|    +--- io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-common:1.6.22
```

As you can see there is no trasnitive dependencies coming from 
`com.a.b:feature-store-lib:0.4`

Need ideas to debug.

Comment: Both Maven and Gradle look for them in Maven repositories. How Maven does it is irrelevant if you're also using Gradle in the other project, though. You're confusing Maven the repository and pom.xml definitions, and Maven the build tool. Gradle uses repositories and poms, but doesn't use the Maven build tool.

Comment: If you posted the relevant code and errors, we could help.

Comment: @JBNizet Right, I am a bit confused between them. But got hold of it now, I am using gradle in another project as well. Now, I am not sure how does gradle build tool look for pom.xml definitions as clearly that isn't working. WIll post the code as well.

Comment: If you posted the relevant code and errors, we could help.

Comment: @JBNizet Posted more detail.

Comment: Apparently, you're writing a pom file to src/main/resources at some point (or not: we don't know when this task is called), and expect that pom to be used by Gradle/Maven. That won't happen. Use a recent version of gradle (it seems you're using a very old one), and read how to properly publish a library in the guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm going to assume that you are producing a pom this way because of some external requirements. Otherwise I would suggest using the publishing plugin as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html#sec:configuring_publishing_tasks). Publishing to artifactory becomes very easy this way.

My first instinct is that you might have used the wrong configuration in your dependency declaration. If you are using a newer version of gradle you should be using the *api* configuration for dependencies that need to be exposed to any user of your artifact.

```groovy
dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7' // Exposed
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' // Not exposed
}
```

For more information I refer to the gradle documentation on this subject: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph